# Calculate date interval in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have data like `date, name, counts`

How can I get the date interval between the first and the last date of each name?

```
SELECT name, SUM(counts), MAX(date)-MIN(date) AS age //this is wrong
FROM tb
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Why is it wrong?  That would be valid in Oracle, giving AGE as the   difference in days.

Comment: Sure, Sql Server, for example, has functions like DATEDIFF. MySql have [DATEDIFF](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff_mysql.asp) too, but with other parameters.

Comment: Do you want the difference in days, months, years?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT name
     , SUM(counts)
     , DATEDIFF(MAX(date), MIN(date))/365 AS age1  --- may need adjustment
     , YEAR(MAX(date)) - YEAR(MIN(date))  AS age2  --- integer result
FROM tb
GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name, SUM(counts), DATEDIFF(MAX(date),MIN(date)) as age
FROM tb
GROUP BY name
```